# How to optimize query

Tags: sqlite, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

I'm using SQLite3 and the following query, It seems like there should be a better performing way to write this query; Is there?

```
Select Name,
    Sum(Case 
       When 
          Used 
             Is Null 
       Then 
          ItemQty
       Else 
          0 
       End) As QtyNotUsed
From 
   ContainersReceived
Group By
   Name
```

Basically my thought (that I can't realize) is something like:

```
Select 
    Distinct Name
From 
   ContainersReceived
```

combined with

```
Select 
   Sum(ItemQty)
From
   ContainersReceived 
Where
    Used Is Null
```

The result I want is a list of all `Name`s and how much is in stock from the table `ContainersReceived`.

UPDATE:

Possible solution is to use:

```
Select 
    Name, 
    Sum(ItemQty)
From ContainersReceived
Where Used Is Null
Group By Name
UNION ALL
Select 
    Name, 
    0
From ContainersReceived
Where Used Is Not Null
Group By Name
```

Comment: Do you want a list of all names and the sum of the `ItemQty` for every group (of rows with same Name)?

Comment: @ypercube Yes and yes. But only the sum of ItemQty where used is null. but I still want to show the names even when Used is null, just under sum Should show 0.

Comment: How many rows does the table have?

Comment: And how many rows have null in the `Used` column (and how many not null)?

Comment: Seems like you're optimizing something that is already optimum. Why are you trying to avoid CASE? Your solution tests the null on each row and goes through the table twice. I'd stick with the very first SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want but this may be it:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Used IS NULL 
           THEN ItemQty 
           ELSE 0 
        END) AS QtyNotUsed
FROM 
    ContainersReceived
GROUP BY
    Name ;
```

To be efficient, add an index on `(Name, Used, ItemQty)`

---

If you have another index, on `(Used, Name, ItemQty)`, this query will be even more efficient - but it will **not** show Names that have no row with `Used IS NULL`:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    SUM(ItemQty) AS QtyNotUsed
FROM 
    ContainersReceived
WHERE
    Used IS NULL 
GROUP BY
    Name ;
```

Comment: This is what I have already, I entered it wrong in the question (fixed now). but what I am looking for is a better performing version of this that doesn't need to do the line by line case function.

Comment: If you had this query, why did you post a question with another, that does not even run?

Comment: It was an accident. Basically is there any way to return 2 queries on top of each other? That's what would be perfect.

Comment: I have updated my question with a possible solution. That shouldn't require the case statement, therefor shouldn't need to evaluate Row by row?

Comment: No, your solution would give some Names 2 times in the result, one with `0` and one with `Qty>0`. Did you try the above with the index? If it is not efficient, then we can discuss.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know about performance of using `UNION` instead of `OR`, but it's not in this case vs. using `CASE` that just add an inline filter.

In your second query you will have two `Sort` actions as a side effect of having two `GORUP BY` statements and also two `Filter` actions with adding a `Concatenation` by using `UNION`.

> **Note:**
>   The count of actions is not a matter in performance in all cases.

I think, If data of `ContainersReceived` table grows to a huge rows, your second query will be slower than your first query.